# Compute curvature of $f(x;\alpha)=\exp(-\alpha x)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let's say that we have a function of one variable, $f\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, which is parametrized by a real parameter $\alpha$. For instance, let's say that we have the function
$$
f(x;\alpha)=\exp(-\alpha x).
$$
How can I compute the curvature of $f$ in each point $x\in\Bbb{R}$?

I am totally new to this field, so if you believe that the question must be close, please let me know. Any advice on the question will be much appreciated though.

Comment: What do you call the curvature of a real valued function? The curvature of its graph? Then you have a formula to compute it, right? What did you get when you applied it?

Comment: @Did, thanks for your quick response, exactly, I mean the curvature of it's graph. Could you please point this formula to me? Sorry, I'm new and I didn't know how to look for it. I should probably delete this question after this.

Comment: First hit for `google: curvature of graph` is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph

Comment: There is a different measure of curvature of a function used in economics in the context of expected utility; the coefficient of absolute risk aversion for a utiiltiy function $u$ is given by $-\frac{u''(x)}{u'(x)}$ (the negative is there because utility functions are usually assumed to be concave).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Did, so that was pretty obvious and the question seems very spammy, if you think I should close it, please let me know. Thanks again!